# ssis [File System Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "Access to the path is denied."

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

So, I have an SSIS package that checks for file existence on the server, copies data from the file onto a table on sql server and moves the file to a done folder.

I have created environment variables and since I have full access to folders and to the server..the package got executed successfully. But, When I selected QA environment in the configuration manager and when I run the package..it's failing to move the file to the done folder and the error in execution result is - [File System Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "Access to the path is denied.".

I have used user variables within the File system task

[image]

[image]

and the package overview

[image]

My question here is - since the file is present in file explorer on QA box and I don't have access..is it the reason for it to fail. But, I am not using my credentials to login at the connection manager level. I am using SQL server authentication (got a service account created).

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you!

Comment: Does the service account have read/write permission to the folder in the QA environment?

Comment: I spoke to one of the DBA guy, and he said that the SQL account cannot be granted permissions to folder in the QA environment and is only applicable to the SQL instance.

Comment: Sounds like he's talking about a SQL Server login, which would be the credentials you're using to log into the SQL Server using SQL Authentication. I was referring to the Windows Service Account that SQL Server uses when running the db engine, SQL Agent, or other service (i.e. reporting services, integration services, etc). If you're going to use a job to kick off the SSIS package, make sure that the SQL Agent service account has permissions to access the folder. The default service account for the SQL Agent is usually `NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT`

Comment: awesome. Thanks a lot for the information. One more question that I have is - do we need to set up a proxy account that has access to windows server as well as SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

> My question here is - since the file is present in file explorer on QA box and I don't have access..is it the reason for it to fail.

This is the reason for the failure, yes.

When running a SSIS package in Visual Studio most things will run under **your** credentials. Yes, you need to specify credentials for some connection managers, but File System Tasks use the Local User's credentials. If you, personally, do not have access to a file, neither does an SSIS package you are running.

Comment: so, any work around for that ? Would deploying the package onto the server and executing the package through a SQL server job agent or manually executing it by right clicking on the package in Integration Services Catalog.

Comment: @tanu Deploying the package the the SQL Server would enable the Server to execute it. Doing so through the Agent would mean your Agent account executes it, via the SSIS Catalog would run it under the credentials of the connected user (via kerboros and double hopping). To truly debug the package, you need access to what it's doing. Personally, my view is that fi you don't have access, you don't for a reason; thus you shoulnd't be trying to spoof your credentials to be able to do so. Security is there for a reason.